best method: check if it would be possible to create and write to a folder
I need to know if a folder might be created or blocked e.g. by a wrong part of the dir parameter. Is there a better solution to check if I can (at a later point of time) create a folder and write to this folder/save files here?
function DirectoryCanExist(dir: string): Boolean;
var
  testDir: string;
begin
  testDir := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(dir) + '__test__';
  try
    ForceDirectories(testDir);
    Result := DirectoryExists(testDir);
    RemoveDir(testDir);
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

This is my calling code:
  if DirectoryCanExist(dir) then
  begin
    ForceDirectories(dir);
    OutputDebugString(PChar('[PASS] -->  ' + dir));
  end
  else
  begin
    OutputDebugString(PChar('[ERROR & DEBUG] -->  ' + dir));
  end;

With this calling code I only get:

First chance exception at $00007FFABBA653AC. Exception class EInOutError with message 'Unable to create directory'. Process VCLGUIAPP.exe (17144)

I need information on the failing dir String. Working dir parameters are not interesting to me, my program will create many directories for sorting files at run time.

DirectoryCanExists needs to be DirectoryCanExist since you can only have one finite verb in a finite verb phrase.

done (change function name), what about this code ?

Yes, this is fine. Just remember, though, that the ability to create and write to a specific directory may change at any time outside of your program’s control. So, go ahead and check, but also be prepared to have the operation possibly fail later.

I don’t understand your edit. “i need the fails” What? (BTW, unless you explicitly configure it to ignore a specific exception, the debugger will always stop when an exception occurs and you’ll need to resume your program to see its non-debug mode behaivor.)

Information like what? You already have the failing dir string as argument to your function.

Ugh - what if testDir already existed and you still insist on RemoveDir(testDir)? That could either be wrong, or it could fail (folder not empty), which then leads to a different exception and a different logical outcome of your Boolean function.

Your DirectoryCanExist() is redundant in your example and can be removed completely. ForceDirectories() returns a boolean indicating success or failure. Use that instead, eg:
if ForceDirectories(dir) then
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar('[PASS] -->  ' + dir));
end
else
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar('[ERROR & DEBUG] -->  ' + dir));
end;

